# Fetching data from JSON containing an array

Tags: ruby, json

I have the following piece of JSON returned to a Ruby RestClient post request:

```
{"importResults":[{"status":"success","id":"ed2a89538d84eff5b92b5baad1fb5a4e"}]}
```

I am trying to retrieve the status (success) and the id (ed2a89538d84eff5b92b5baad1fb5a4e).

I tried the following code:

```
jdoc = JSON.parse(jsonAbove)
status = jdoc.fetch("importResults").fetch("status")
```

This is giving me back the error `TypeError: can't convert String into Integer`.

I know it's because there is an array in the response that I'm getting this error but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
status = jdoc.fetch("importResults").first.fetch("status")
```

Answer (score 4):

As many others have already said, you need `first` in your request.

```
status = jdoc.fetch("importResults").first.fetch("status")
```

It looks like you are new to this.  I would suggest using irb to mess around with things.  For example, you could type `s = jdoc.fetch("importResults")` and look at the result.  You can then play around with the `s` variable in the console and see what works.  `s.first`, `s.class`, `s[0]` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Right, so it is an array. Get its first (or another appropriate) element and proceed.

```
status = jdoc.fetch("importResults").first.fetch("status")
#                                      ^^
```

Comment: Upvoted yours since you were first to answer, though I tried to provide alternate syntax. :)

Answer (score 3):

That's because you need to get the first item from the array.  Change this:

```
status = jdoc["importResults"].first["status"]
```

Alternatively:

```
status = jdoc["importResults"][0]["status"]
```